# Artifactory behind Nginx without directory /artifactory in the url

Tags: nginx, tomcat

On our old server (hosted), Artifactory was running behind an Apache proxy. The public url was http://repo.example.com/

Our hosting provider moved us to a new server.

- A new version of Artifactory was installed, the data exported from the old server and imported in the new server
- Artifactory is now running behind Nginx
- The public url is now http://repo.example.com/artifactory/

We have asked our hosting provider to change the url back to http://repo.example.com/, because now our Jenkins jobs are breaking, and because external users may rely on the url. They told me that I first need to change some setting in Artifactory (no details what exactly), but the only setting I can find in the web interface, is the custom url base, and that is already set to http://repo.example.com. My best guess is that something needs to be changed in the configuration of the Tomcat server that runs Artifactory but

1. Tomcat configuration is outside my field of expertise
2. I cannot change the configuration myself, I don't have write access to those files.

What I actually need, is a configuration that I can send to our hosting provider, so they can just copy paste from my email.

Short version:
*How can I make Artifactory, running behind Nginx, accessible on http://repo.example.com?*

EDIT:
This is the current `/usr/local/artifactory/tomcat/conf/server.xml`:

`<Server port="8015" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8083"/> 
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"/>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>`

Would it be enough to change this to:

`<Server port="8015" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8083"/> 
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps">
                <Context path="" docBase="."/>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>`

As mentioned, I do not have root access to the server so I cannot modify this myself.

Comment: Yeah it works now and I don't know exactly how the hosting provider made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what they probably put in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/java_artifactory` to make it work:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  artifactory.java.********** ;


  error_log  /var/log/nginx/java/artifactory_error.log;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/java/artifactory_access.log;

  location / {
    # rewrite ^/?$ http://**********/webapp/home.html;
    # rewrite ^/artifactory(.*)$ http://**********$1;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    # proxy_pass http://localhost:8083/artifactory/;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8083/;
  }
}
```